# List all faces for all edges

Tags: python, cython

A very simple question:
how to compute efficiently in Python (or Cython) the following quantity.

Given the list of polygons in 3D (polygon

There is a list of polygons given in the following form:

```
vertex = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0],[1, 0, 0],[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]], order = 'F').T
polygons = np.array([3, 0, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 3 ,4])
```

i.e. polygon is a 1D array, which contains entries of the form [N,i1,i2,i3,i4,...],
N is the number of vertices in a polygons and then the id numbers of the vertices in the vertex array (in the example above there is one triangle with 3 vertices [0,1,2] and one polygon with 4 vertices [1,2,3,4]

I need to compute the information: a list of all edges and for each edge the information 
which faces contain this edge.

And I need to do it fast: the number of vertices can be large.

**Update**
The polygon is closed, i.e. a polygon `[4, 0, 1, 5, 7]` means that there are 4 vertices and edges are `0-1, 1-5, 5-7, 7-0`
The face is a synonim to polygon in fact.

Comment: could you define what are edges and faces in your case ?

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if this is the fastest option, most probably not, but it works. I think the slowest part is `edges.index((v, polygon[i + 1]))` where we have to find if this edge is already in list. Vertex array is not really needed since edge is a pair of vertex indexes. I used face_index as a reference to polygon index since you didn't write what face is.

```
vertex = [[0,0,0], [0,0,1], [0,1,0],[1,0,0],[0.5,0.5,0.5]]
polygons = [3,0,1,2,4,1,2,3,4]
_polygons = polygons
edges = []
faces = []
face_index = 0

while _polygons:
    polygon = _polygons[1:_polygons[0] + 1]
    polygon.append(polygon[0])
    _polygons = _polygons[_polygons[0] + 1:]

    for i, v in enumerate(polygon[0:-1]):
        if not (v, polygon[i + 1]) in edges:
            edges.append((v, polygon[i + 1]))
            faces.append([face_index, ])
        else:
            faces[edges.index((v, polygon[i + 1]))].append(face_index)
    face_index += 1

edges = map(lambda edge, face: (edge, face), edges, faces)

print edges

<<< [((0, 1), [0]), ((1, 2), [0, 1]), ((2, 0), [0]), ((2, 3), [1]), ((3, 4), [1]), ((4, 1), [1])]
```

You can make it faster by removing line `polygon.append(polygon[0])` and append first vertice of polygon to vertices list in polygon manually, which shouldn't be a problem.
I mean change `polygons = [3,0,1,2,4,1,2,3,4]` into `polygons = [3,0,1,2,0,4,1,2,3,4,1]`.

PS Try to use [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It is a code typing style. It says that you should put a space after every comma in iterables so it's eaasier to read.